# Spring boot connection reset after a few minutes in docker container

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, datasource

The backend runs in a docker container. It runs with spring boot & security and works fine. The frontend runs in another container as well. All works fine until out of nowhere this exception is thrown. I only noticed this exception after I idled a few minutes (normaly between 5 and 10 min).

> WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
>   ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : I/O Error: Connection reset 
>    ERROR 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
>   java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
>           at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
>           at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:195) ~[na:1.8.0_111-internal]
>   .....

The connection to the Database is available all the time. The weird thing is, that this error is only thrown when I run my project with docker. If I run it with eclipse & node.js the error don't occurs. The only thing I noticed was, that a few minutes after I loged in and idled, I got automaticly loged out when I tried to do something. I don't know if this has any connection with the orgiginal error.

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=databaseURL
spring.datasource.username=SQLusername
spring.datasource.password=Password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.initialSize=100
spring.datasource.minIdle=10

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=250
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=30000
spring.datasource.test-on-borrow=true
spring.datasource.test-while-idle=true
spring.datasource.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=21600000
spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=43200000


spring.datasource.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

I'm glad for every suggestion that could help to fix this proplem.

Comment: Which DB engine are you dealing with? Do you get any errors from the DB engine itself?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem months ago!
This happens because the jvm doesn’t have memory enough to accept this request!

This error is intermittent and is very difficult to find your root cause!

Try this:
Put in your Dockerfile some flags to solve it

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-XX:+TieredCompilation","-XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1", "-jar","yourJar.jar"]
```

More details here: https://jpbempel.github.io/2020/05/22/startup-containers-tieredcompilation.html

Sometimes the problem can be memory. When you start your container with java, the jvm default heap memory is 1/4 of total memory of container.
Then you can use the flag ***-XX:MaxRAMFraction*** where your value has a range 1 to 4.

More details here: https://merikan.com/2019/04/jvm-in-a-container/#java-8u131-and-java-9

Good luck!